# File Date column – is yyyymmdd but should it be dd/mm/ccyy

Tags: sql-server

How can I get in SQL server a file date in the following format: dd/mm/ccyy

I have this, but this creates  yyyymmdd

```
 CONVERT (char(8),Getdate(),112) AS [File date]
```

how can I get  dd/mm/ccyy ?

Comment: I would recommend leaving formatting to the front end. But if you really must format dates you use convert and then the style you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `CONVERT (char(10),Getdate(),103) AS [File date]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CONVERT (char,Getdate(),103)
```

A useful reference is date formats: [date format cheatsheet](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/sql-server-date-format-cheatsheet.html)

Comment: Another good source of reference is the actual documentation. :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017