# Convert from MM-DD-YYYY to CCYY-MM-DD in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

```
,CONVERT (char,Getdate(),110) AS 'date_needed_by'
```

which results in 03-12-2019

However, I need 2019-03-12

I have not spotted this particular format in any of the date guides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Date column – is yyyymmdd but should it be dd/mm/ccyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934135/file-date-column-is-yyyymmdd-but-should-it-be-dd-mm-ccyy)

Answer (score 1):

-- If TSQL, 
 Select Format(GetDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS 'date_needed_by';

Comment: This site has your answer, http://sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121) as [test]
```

works and results in 2019-03-12